# APACHE VHost - How to check multiple folders to check if the first one fails

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have the following Virtual Host config block which works.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot"
#   VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/www"
#   VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/public"
#   VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/wwwroot/public"
#   VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/sites/%1/"
   ServerName sites.dev
   ServerAlias *.dev
   ServerAlias *.dev.*.xip.io
   UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

Checking out the # tags in the Vhost I have tried adding these and the fail. I have tried adding another VHost block with only the VDocRoot path changed and this is not working. Any help anyone can provide would be amazing!

UPDATE:

I should mention this is for my local dev machine (mac os x)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just list multiple DocumentRoot or VirtualDocumentRoot.

Here's a recipe for mod_rewrite:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html#multipledirs

Comment: I am wondering how to have the .htaccess file prop through all file structure. I currently have a sites folder with all website names as folders in those folders would be where wwwroot or www or public folders reside. I am new with .htaccess and am unsure how to get sites folder to use this .htaccess instead of the virtual hosts I have going. If I take vhosts out completely I think it may make other sites not work. Any help you can give would be appreciated :)